# Chrome/Safari jquery event on click not trigger

Tags: jquery

I have an event with jquery like :

```
$(document).on('click', '.etatChange > option', function() {
```

When i test on Mozilla it's ok, but with Chrome or Safari the event is not trigged... Do you know why ?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect when a `select` element's value changes, you should use the `change` event:

```
$(document).on('change', '.etatChange', function() { ... });
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at hand -- we don't know if there is a valid reason or not for using the click event over the change event.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Chrome and Safari do not give `option` elements a `click` event. http://jsfiddle.net/g4dgvyno/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ah, you should add that to your answer, but you were right either way. Good job

Answer (score 1):

Tried putting it under document ready and change event to change? You are not clicking on option, you are changing select value here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('change', '.etatChange', function() {
  }
});
```